# How to create a dictionary to cache values in python?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to improve the recursive function for Collatz sequence in Python as my teacher mentioned to make it more efficient. I am storing calculations in a dictionary which repeats in other sequences, for example: if you calculate the collatz of 4 we realize it's 4,2,1

If we then calculate the collatz of 7 it's a bunch of numbers but the important part is that it eventually has a "4" in the sequence. which means we are going to be calculating the collatz(4) twice, once for the "4" value and again for the "7" value. if we could for example reuse the 4 value we could prevent this computation from happening twice. For some reason, my code is only printing 2,1,1 and throws an error after that. Can someone please help with this (sorry for the bad indentation, stack overflow didn't let me indent it properly)? I tried the lru cache method, it works but my teacher expects to create the dictionary by ourselves instead of using lru cache

```
def collatz_up_to_n(n):
   for i in range(n):
   better_collatz_up_to_n(i+1)
   print("\n")
def better_collatz_up_to_n(n):
    print(n, " ", end="")
    a_list = [n]
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        a_list.extend(better_collatz_up_to_n(n // 2))
    if n in a_list == collatz_up_to_n(n):
        values = {n}
    else:
        a_list.extend(better_collatz_up_to_n(n * 3 + 1))
    if n in a_list == collatz_up_to_n(n):
        valuesOdd = {n}
    return a_list,values,valuesOdd
    print (n)
print("The Collatz sequence up to 10 is: ")
collatz_up_to_n(10)
```

Comment: `if n in a_list == collatz_up_to_n(n):` That looks odd. `n in a_list` will be `True` or `False`. Also, `collatz_up_to_n()` does not return a value.

Comment: this will never terminate, as if n=4 you call collatz_up_to_n(4) which will eventually call better_collatz_up_to_n(4), which will call collatz_up_to_n(4) and so on forever

Comment: The cache needs to be a global variable. If it's a local variable it starts fresh every time you call the function, which negates the purpose.

Comment: Nothing executes after a `return` statement, so `print(n)` will never print anything.

Comment: You can use the built-in [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the dict between uses of your function, you can't define it as a local variable. Otherwise, it disappears when the function ends, and is created all-new at the next call, without saving previously encountered values.

Here are three ways to do this, using an object attribute, a default argument, or a decorator from module `functools`. I used the Fibonacci function rather than the Collatz sequence, so as not to spoil the problem completely for you. I tested the cached Fibonacci functions by trying to compute `fib(40)`. A bad implementation of Fibonacci without caching would take an awfully long time to compute `fib(40)`; the three functions below return the result immediately.

```py
# FIRST WAY: using an object attribute
def fib1(n):
    if n in fib1.cache:
        return fib1.cache[n]
    else:
        fib1.cache[n] = fib1(n-2) + fib1(n-1)
        return fib1.cache[n]

fib1.cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}

print(fib1(11))
# 89
print(fib1(40))
# 102334155

# SECOND WAY: using a default argument
def fib2(n, cache={0: 0, 1: 1}):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    else:
        cache[n] = fib2(n-2) + fib2(n-1)
        return cache[n]

print(fib2(11))
# 89
print(fib2(40))
# 102334155
```

However, there is a third way. Since caching values is not particularly original and is often useful, you can use `functools.cache` to automatically cache the outputs of a function:

- [Documentation on `functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)

```py
import functools

@functools.cache
def fib3(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-1)

print(fib3(11))
# 89
print(fib3(40))
# 102334155
```

For contrast, here is the bad way that doesn't properly save the cache from one call to the next:

```py
# BAD WAY: Don't do this. The cache is local to each call, and erased as soon as the function returns.
def fib0(n):
    cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    else:
        cache[n] = fib0(n-2) + fib0(n-1)
        return cache[n]

print(fib0(11))
# 89
print(fib0(40))
# TAKES AWFULLY LONG TIME
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, I understand. The only problem is that when I try to put the cache statement within the function definition, it says n is not defined and when I use it as a object attribute, it is not working either. Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: @Shri I don't understand what you mean. Who says `n` is not defined? What did you do? I tested the code in my answer before posting my answer. There was no error message. If you got an error message, I assume you did something wrong. I cannot guess what you did. What does "it is not working either" even mean? Is it "not working" because it returns the wrong values? Or because it returns the correct values, but too slow? Or because there is an error message? What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I just fixed the problem. Thank you very much!